# How can I wrap <div> within <a> without breaking the width or layout of the <div>?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, anchor

This example works fine as expected evenly spacing out the blue boxes horizontally.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  background: lightblue;
  border: thin solid blue;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></div>
</div>
```

In the above example, only the text snippets are links. Now I want to turn the entire blue boxes into links. Here is my attempt.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  background: lightblue;
  border: thin solid blue;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#"><div class="box">Lorem Ipsum</div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="box">Lorem Ipsum</div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="box">Lorem Ipsum</div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="box">Lorem Ipsum</div></a>
</div>
```

Why did the layout of the boxes break now? How can I fix this?

Comment: move the class box to the `a` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because now the div is taking 15% width of `a` tag. Though, you don't need the div in real. Just move the class to `a` tag.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  background: lightblue;
  border: thin solid blue;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="box" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
  <a class="box" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
  <a class="box" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
  <a class="box" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
</div>
```